# npx command got stuck/frozen

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I have node version v20.3.0, and npm version 9.7.1.

The problem is whenever I try to run the `npx create` - any kind of command it'll freeze in a state like this.

[stuck npx command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vvMV.png)

What should I do to fix this problem? I have tried adding the node path in the env variable but it didn't work out. I also have tried commands like `npm cache clean`, and also tried to reinstall node

I can't use the npm in VS Code, but commands like `npm init -y` are working.

On the other hand development servers are also not working.

Comment: See here https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4028. Very possibly related. All the commands that arent working are the ones that access network. Try disabling ipv6 as per thread.